# In a public instance of Jupyter hub: how to prevent users to navigate through the directory system of the server?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

Is there any way of avoiding users of a public instance of Jupyterhub to navigate (using magic commands) through the directory system of the public server deploying the public instance? (in my particular case the users should be able to import a given python package from their notebooks but shouldn't be able to see the source code of that python package, neither some other critical directories of the server). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the perfect job for Docker! Jupyterhub has a reference implementation of Jupyterhub using Docker to containerise user servers [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker)

The users will be given their own folders that they can modify but won't be able to access the server's code at all

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input! just one question: then, will the users be able to import our python package from their jupyter notebooks even if that package is located in one of the server's directories they cannot access? (I thought python's "import" was under the same access restrictions as the user). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file of the JupyterHub, you can put:

`c.Spawner.notebook_dir=/path/to/shared/folder`. That will stop users to see your environment through UI, but they will still be able to browse using Terminal. You can use host operating system mechanisms to allow user only particular operations (not to be sudo/root user, create group etc.). JupyterHub uses host operating users to allow the logging by default.